# Net User Command: Searching for list of users?

Tags: windows, command, windows-net-command

I am using this command

```
net user joe.blogs /domain
```

what syntax do I use to search 20 users? How to separate the names to make it search for the users?

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported, you can't give multiple users to this command: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc771865(v=ws.11)

You should take a look at [Get-ADUser](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2019-ps) instead